# Obter valores das checkboxes selecionadas e seus respectivos preços

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Bom, estou desenvolvendo um sistema de pedidos online, inicialmente só para fins de aprendizado, só que me deparei com algo que não faço a mínima ideia de como fazer e apreciaria imensamente qualquer tipo de ajuda.
Na página **produtos.php** eu estabeleço duas conexões com o DB e busco os produtos presentes na tabela *produtos* por categoria e os acréscimos existentes na tabela *acrescimos*:

```
$sql = "SELECT p.id_produto, p.nome_produto, p.preco_produto, p.id_categoria, c.nome_categoria FROM produtos p, categorias c WHERE c.id_categoria = p.id_categoria ORDER BY p.id_categoria, p.nome_produto";
$stmt = $conexao->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

$sql2 = "SELECT id_acrescimo, nome_acrescimo, preco_acrescimo FROM acrescimos ORDER BY nome_acrescimo";
$stmt2 = $conexao->prepare($sql2);
$stmt2->execute();

$num = $stmt->rowCount();
$categoria = null;

if($num>0)
{
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        extract($row);
        if($categoria != $id_categoria)
        {
            if(!is_null($categoria)) { echo "</table>"; }

        echo "<h1>{$nome_categoria}</h1>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>NOME</th>
                <th>PREÇO</th>
                <th>QUANTIDADE</th>";
                if($id_categoria == 1) echo" <th>ACRÉSCIMOS</th>";
            echo "</tr>";

            $categoria = $id_categoria;
        }
        $preco_produto_reajustado = number_format($preco_produto, 2, ",", ".");
        echo "
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class='id-produto' style='display: none'>{$id_produto}</div>
                <div class='nome-produto'>{$nome_produto}</div></td>
                <td>R&#36;{$preco_produto_reajustado}
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type='number' name='quantidade' value='1' min='1' max='20'/>
            </td>";
            if($id_categoria == 1)
            {
                echo "<td>";
                while ($row = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                {
                    extract($row);
                    $preco_acrescimo_reajustado = number_format($preco_acrescimo, 2, ",", ".");
                    echo "
                    <input type='checkbox' name='{$nome_acrescimo}' value='{$nome_acrescimo}'/>{$nome_acrescimo} - R&#36;{$preco_acrescimo_reajustado} <input type='number' name='quantidade_acr[]' value='1' min='1' max='5'/><br/>
                    ";
                }
                echo "</td>";
            }
            echo "<td>
                <form class='adicionar'>
                    <button type='submit'>Adicionar</button>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
```

Como puderam ver com este código, se o ID da categoria correspondente for igual a 1, outra coluna será criada na *table*. A coluna **Acréscimos**. E é aí que se encontra o meu maior problema. Se analisaram bem o código, puderam ver que meu *output* será algo como:
[image: Output]
Notaram as *checkboxes* presentes na coluna **Acréscimos**? Então, o que estou tentando fazer (sem sucesso) é, no ato do *click* no botão **Adicionar**, obter os valores das *checkboxes* selecionadas de acordo com seus nomes e preços existentes na tabela *acrescimos*. Mas como fazer isso?
Eu preciso obter esses valores e armazená-los em variáveis para posteriormente inseri-los dentro da *SESSION* e exibi-los junto com os outros no carrinho do usuário. No **produtos.php** eu tenho uma função de *jQuery* que armazena os dados da linha selecionada em variáveis para depois serem inseridos em suas determinadas variáveis na *SESSION*:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.adicionar').on('submit', function()
    {
        var id_produto = $(this).closest('tr').find('.id-produto').text();
        var nome_produto = $(this).closest('tr').find('.nome-produto').text();
        var quantidade = $(this).closest('tr').find('input').val();
        window.location.href = "adicionar.php?id_produto=" + id_produto + "&nome_produto=" + nome_produto + "&quantidade=" + quantidade;
        return false;
    });
});
```

No arquivo **adicionar.php** eu busco no DB o ID e nome do produto selecionado para então obter o preço do mesmo. Se meu retorno for *true*, o *script* prossegue adicionando os dados na *SESSION*:

```
if (isset($_GET['id_produto']) && $_GET['id_produto'] != "")
{
    if(isset($_SESSION['carrinho']))
    {
        $contar = count($_SESSION['carrinho']);
        $id_produto_sessao = $contar++;
    }
    else
    {
        $id_produto_sessao = 0;
    }
    $id_produto = isset($_GET['id_produto']) ? $_GET['id_produto'] : "";
    $nome_produto = isset($_GET['nome_produto']) ? $_GET['nome_produto'] : "";
    $quantidade = isset($_GET['quantidade']) ? $_GET['quantidade'] : "";

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE id_produto LIKE '{$id_produto}' AND nome_produto LIKE '{$nome_produto}' LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $conexao->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();

    $num = $stmt->rowCount();

    if($num == 1)
    {
        if($quantidade <= 0 || $quantidade > 20)
        {
            header('Location: produtos.php?acao=quantidadeinvalida&nome_produto=' . $nome_produto);
        }
        else if(!isset($_SESSION['carrinho']))
        {
            $_SESSION['carrinho'] = array();
        }
        if(isset($_SESSION['carrinho']))
        {
            while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
                extract($row);
                $colunas = array
                (
                    'id_produto_sessao' => $id_produto_sessao,
                    'id_produto' => $id_produto,
                    'nome_produto' => $nome_produto,
                    'preco_produto' => $preco_produto,
                    'quantidade' => $quantidade
                );
            }
            $_SESSION['carrinho'][$id_produto_sessao] = $colunas;
            header('Location: produtos.php?acao=adicionado&nome_produto=' . $nome_produto);
        }
    }   
    else
    {
        redirecionar_para("produtos.php");
    }
}
```

Notem que a quantidade informada é obtida com o *jQuery* e passada para a *SESSION*. Creio que terei que fazer algo parecido para obter os dados referentes às *checkboxes* selecionadas, mas não faço ideia de como fazer isso. Iria colocar também o código que consta no arquivo **carrinho.php** e que tem como finalidade exibir os dados presentes na *SESSION carrinho*, mas isso vai deixar a pergunta extensa demais. Acho que primeiro devo conseguir armazenar os dados dessas *checkboxes*. A tarefa de exibi-los depois não deve ser tão difícil. Mas voltando ao problema em pauta, como obter os valores de cada uma das *checkboxes* selecionadas anteriormente e também inseri-los nessa *SESSION*? Como implementar isso no meu sistema?

Comment: Você quer algo assim? https://jsfiddle.net/724xyyq4/ (Claro, não está exatamente como você precisa... mas a ideia de pegar os `checkbox` é a mesma... só editar para a sua necessidade)

Comment: @RafaelWithoeft Obrigado pelo comentário! Sim, é mais ou menos isso. Mas eu preciso especificar os preços de cada um dos acréscimos e multiplicá-los pela quantidade informada. No carrinho depois pode constar algo como "Produto: Pizza, Acréscimos: 2xQueijo, 1xAlho, total: R$(valor da soma dos preços dos acréscimos multiplicados pela quantidade de cada um)"

Answer (score 1):

Se mudares o HTML um pouco facilitas as coisas. Muda:

```
<td>
    <input type='checkbox' name='acr[0]' value='Queijo'/>Queijo - R&#36;2,00 <input type='number' name='quantidade_acr[0]' value='1' min='1' max='5'/><br/>
    <input type='checkbox' name='acr[1]' value='Alho'/>Alho - R&#36;0,50 <input type='number' name='quantidade_acr[1]' value='1' min='1' max='5'/><br/>
    <input type='checkbox' name='acr[2]' value='Oregano'/>Orégano - R&#36;0,50 <input type='number' name='quantidade_acr[2]' value='1' min='1' max='5'/><br/>
</td>
```

para:

```
<td classe="acr">
   <input type='checkbox' name='acr[]' value='{"tipo": "Queijo", "preco": 2.0}'/>Queijo - R&#36;2,00 <input type='number' name='quantidade_acr[0]' value='1' min='1' max='5'/><br/>
   etc...
```

Assim no valor dessas checkboxes já tens o preço e tens uma classe com essa `td`.

Depois podes fazer assim para passar isso para um JavaScript:

```
var dados = $('.acr input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function (i) {
    var data = JSON.parse(this.value);
    var qtd = this.checked ? parseInt($(this).next('input').val(), 10) : 0;
    var preco = data.preco;
    var toString = {
        tipo: data.tipo,
        preco: data.preco,
        qdt: qtd,
        total: qtd * data.preco
    };
    var obj = {};
    obj['acr_' + i] = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(toString));
    return obj;
});

var queryString = dados.map(function () {
    return $.param(this, true)
}).get().join('&');
```

Isso vai criar uma array `dados` com objetos com tipo, preco, qtd e total. Depois converte essa informação toda `numa _query string_`, que vejo que usas no teu código. Assim podes juntar o que está nessa variável `queryString` ao GET que fazes quando tens `window.location.href =  ...` lembra-te de juntar `&` entre cada parte desse url.

Se fizeres com AJAX podes fazer assim, dentro da função que inicia o envio para o servidor:

```
var obj = {};
var dados = $('.acr input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function (i) {
    var data = JSON.parse(this.value);
    var qtd = this.checked ? parseInt($(this).next('input').val(), 10) : 0;
    var preco = data.preco;
    var dados = {
        tipo: data.tipo,
        preco: data.preco,
        qdt: qtd,
        total: qtd * data.preco
    };
    obj['acr_' + i] = dados;
});
$.post(url, obj, function (res) {
    console.log(res);
});
```

Se tiveres problemas a recuperar isso no PHP coloca outra pergunta que podemos ajudar mais.

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lubvpnz5/

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta, Sergio! Estou estudando seu código, mas antes poderia me esclarecer uma dúvida? Como JS é client-side o usuário pode ser capaz de editar o preço do acréscimo? Por exemplo, `<input type='checkbox' name='acr[]' value='{"tipo": "Queijo", "preco": 2.0}'/>Queijo - R&#36;2,00 <input type='number' name='quantidade_acr[0]' value='1' min='1' max='5'/><br/>` Obter o preço a partir do JS é seguro?

Comment: @M.Victor isso é um risco sim. Mas vejo que no teu código estás a usar query string, devias usar POST. Usando POST era o melhor, e podes usar o HTML que sugeri em cima, e fazes o processamento no PHP.

Comment: O problema em usar POST é que, como você pôde ver, existem vários formulários com a classe adicionar. Uso jQuery para obter os valores mais próximos de cada formulário com essa classe e passá-los para a Query String. Não sei como fazer isso com POST, visto que há várias classes com o mesmo nome. Até facilitaria se eu fizesse tudo a partir da página dos produtos ao invés de passar para o arquivo adicionar.php. Você tem alguma ideia de como fazer isso? Pode editar sua resposta com um exemplo de POST que funcione para mim, por gentileza?

Comment: @M.Victor porque nõ fazes isso com AJAX? assim podes enviar via POST. Juntei código para enviares via AJAX.

Comment: Não entendi como implementar isso com os demais dados que obtenho (id do produto, nome, preço, etc). Não há problema para mim usando Query String porque verifico se o ID e o nome do produto existem no DB lá no adicionar.php. Os dados só são inseridos na SESSION se eles existirem. Por isso lá na pergunta eu disse "Devo ter uma tabela no DB correspondente aos Acréscimos com seus devidos nomes e preços?" Porque fazendo por server-side o usuário não tem como alterar dados importantes como por exemplo, o preço. Não teria como fazer algo assim? Guardar os nomes e preços dos acréscimos no DB?

Comment: Sergio, eu editei a pergunta. Estou tentando fazer da maneira que lhe disse: criei a tabela para os acréscimos, com ID, nome e preço e fiz um loop idêntico ao dos produtos para criar uma checkbox para cada acréscimo. Estou estacado agora, meu conhecimento atual não me permite prosseguir!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer o seguinte, no seu formulário, coloque o atributo data-(o parâmetro que quer capturar):

```
<input type='checkbox' name='acr[0]' data-id="1" data-valor="2.00" value='Queijo'/>Queijo - R&#36;2,00 <input type='number' name='quantidade_acr[0]' value='1' step="1" min='1' max='5'/><br/>
                <input type='checkbox' data-id="2" data-valor="0.50" name='acr[1]' value='Alho'/>Alho - R&#36;0,50 <input type='number' name='quantidade_acr[1]' value='1' step="1" min='1' max='5'/><br/>
                <input type='checkbox' data-id="3" data-valor="0.50" name='acr[2]' value='Oregano'/>Orégano - R&#36;0,50 <input type='number' name='quantidade_acr[2]' value='1'step="1" min='1' max='5'/><br/>

<button id="salvar">Salva</button>
```

Depois crie o método em jquery para salvar os dados:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#salvar').on('click', function() {
        var list = [];
         $('[name*="acr"]:checked').each(function(key) {

             var qtde = $('[name*="quantidade_acr['+key+']"]').val();
             var produto = $(this).val();
             var id = $(this).data('id');
             var valor = $(this).data('valor');
             var total = qtde * valor;
            list[key] = {
                          produto: produto,
                          quantidade: qtde,
                          id: id,
                          valor: valor,
                          total_valor: total
                         };

           });
          /* aqui eu dei uma saída em HTML
             do JSON apenas para exibir, o
             ideal é que você envie esse
             array para o seu método post. */
           alert(JSON.stringify(list));

    });
});
```

Aqui está o exemplo:
**https://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/kumyaj8g/**

Aqui um exemplo mais complexo:
**http://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/nq9Lts0f/1/**